# How to get access token and refresh token ( rest_framework_jwt ) in a single API in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I need to get access token and refresh token in a single API, Currently I have 2 API's for both access and refresh tokens

```
url(r'^token-auth', view.ObtainJWTView.as_view(), name='token-auth'),
url(r'^token-refresh', refresh_jwt_token),
```

I need one more API for both

Answer (score 1):

you don't need more api

```
url(r'^token-auth', view.ObtainJWTView.as_view(), name='token-auth'),
```

this will return access and refresh token

and the other will return new access token when you post refresh token

```
url(r'^token-refresh', refresh_jwt_token),
```

check docs

https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#usage

if you are still confused let me know
you can make new custome view and use the to serializers used in the above views

Comment: I 'm using JSONWebTokenAPIView , This will return only access token

Comment: Is there any way to get refresh token and access token inside django view ?

Comment: can you put link here for this package

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-jwt/ this pakage not supported any more

Comment: it will be better if you use https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: I have used
pip install djangorestframework-jwt
this package

Comment: this need to overwrite view and inject refresh token inside response in post method

Comment: https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/views.py

Comment: i checked this package returning refresh and access here don't make sense because this package doesn't return the refresh token as you expect it refresh the access token if not expired which mean you only use one token(access token) and before it expired you request to refresh it again by getting a new access token with the same token, weird :::))))